# Is there a way to refinish underside of a toilet seat?

Tags: bathroom, toilet, old-house, refinishing

I have an old-ish toilet seat that has eroded a bit on the underside. Picture below. Is there a way to fix this? Is there a material I can use to paint over it or something?

[image]

Comment: What's the seat made of? You could probably just spray paint it, but unless it's got some special value, a replacement isn't terribly expensive.

Comment: I'm not sure. How would you figure out what it's made of? And is spray paint water resistant enough on its own, or would I need to seal/finish it with something else after?

Comment: looks like it is similar to particle board